Failed to get symbol RegisterCustomOps with error: dlsym(0xbe91bda0, RegisterCustomOps): symbol not found
Reproduction

Fork the onnxruntime_flutter Link to the flutter plugin in pub.dev
Go to lib/src/ort_session.dart
In the OrtSessionOptions class ligne 242
Add the registerCustomOpsLibrary method  void registerCustomOpsLibrary(String libPath) {  final ppv = calloc<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void>>();  final statusPtr = OrtEnv.instance.ortApiPtr.ref.RegisterCustomOpsLibrary      .asFunction<      bg.OrtStatusPtr Function(          ffi.Pointer<bg.OrtSessionOptions>, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char>, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void>>)>()(_ptr, libPath.toNativeUtf8().cast<ffi.Char>(), ppv);  OrtStatus.checkOrtStatus(statusPtr); }
Add  onnxruntime_extenciens in the example/android android dependency inside app/build.gradle. dependency: implementation "com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-extensions-android:0.9.0".
Add onnxruntime-extensions-cios pod inside the example/ios/podfile, execute pod install in the terminal and add the onnxruntime_extension.xcframework provided by the installed  pod following those stepsRunner > TARGETS > Runner > build Phases > Embed Frameworks.
Go to the example folder > vad_iterator.dart > initModel method
Add the registerCustomOps implementation   if(Platform.isAndroid) {    _sessionOptions!.registerCustomOpsLibrary('libortextensions.so');  } else if(Platform.isIOS){    _sessionOptions!.registerCustomOpsLibrary('onnxruntime_extensions.framework/onnxruntime_extensions');  }
Run the application on both Android and IOS platforms

I should montion that the onnxruntime_flutter use ffi to interop with native c/c++ code.
Link to fork with reproduction
Expected result
Onnxruntime extensions registred successfully.
Actual result

Android works fine

Ios shows the following error:


\[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)\] Unhandled Exception: code=1, message=Failed to get symbol RegisterCustomOps with error: dlsym(0xbe91bda0, RegisterCustomOps): symbol not found
#0      OrtStatus.checkOrtStatus (package:onnxruntime/src/ort_status.dart:29:5)
#1      OrtSessionOptions.registerCustomOpsLibrary (package:onnxruntime/src/ort_session.dart:273:15)
#2      VadIterator.initModel (package:onnxruntime_example/vad_iterator.dart:67:24)

I tried many solutions like those mentioned in [Link to a simular github issue] but no one works for this issue. Can anyone give an explanation or have faced this issue?
